# Tuple within a tuple error

Tags: python, tuples

I'm trying to get integer values which represent the elements of a tuple which is itself an element of another tuple.

```
a1 = (1,1,2,3)
a2 = (3,1,1,2)
a3 = (2,3,1,1)
a4 = (1,2,3,1)

a = [a1, a2, a3, a4]

print(a[1[1]])
```

The result is: `'TypeError: 'int' object is unsubscriptable'`. How could I get the correct answer (which is 1, since the second entry of a2 is 1)?

Comment: and this is just a total nitpick: `a` is actually a list (of tuples), not a tuple of tuples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because what you mean is:

```
print(a[1][1])
```

Your expression contains `1[1]`, which explains the error: you are trying to index an integer, but ints do not support this. What you need is take `a[1]`, which gives `a2`, and then take its 2nd element: `a[1][1]`.